# Averaging months in a year within a csv file

Tags: python

Say I have a csv file as follows:

```
GL000004250,1958.0833333333333,-1.4821428571428572
GL000004250,1958.1666666666667,-2.586206896551724
GL000004250,1958.25,-1.5733333333333333
GL000004250,1958.3333333333333,4.680000000000001
GL000004250,1958.4166666666667,9.944827586206895
GL000004250,1958.5,12.874193548387098
GL000004250,1958.5833333333333,12.21290322580645
GL000004250,1958.6666666666667,7.18148148148148
GL000004250,1958.75,2.187096774193549
GL000004250,1958.8333333333333,-0.9066666666666666
GL000004250,1958.9166666666667,0.3777777777777777
GL000004250,1959.0,0.43214285714285744
GL000004250,1959.0833333333333,-6.432142857142857
GL000004250,1959.1666666666667,-6.806451612903226
GL000004250,1959.25,0.6933333333333334
GL000004250,1959.3333333333333,5.780645161290322
GL000004250,1959.4166666666667,8.343333333333332
GL000004250,1959.5,10.71935483870968
GL000004250,1959.5833333333333,10.216129032258062
```

Where the second column is the year in decimal form and the third column is the data. I would like the program to find all the values from 1958 and average them, then 1959 and average them, etc.

Comment: What have you tried till now?

Answer (score 1):

If you're a beginner, start with the basics. Try with a loop and a dictionary to get a better handle on Python.

```
import numpy as np
with open(csvfile,'r') as f:
    yearAvgs = dict()
    data = f.read().split('\n')
    for line in data:
        if line:
            year = int(float(line.split(',')[1]))
            val = float(line.split(',')[2])
            if year not in yearAvgs:
                yearAvgs[year] = []
            yearAvgs[year].append(val)

for k, v in yearAvgs.items():
    avg = np.mean(v)
    print ("Year = ",k,": Mean = ",avg)
```

Edit: If you're looking for a solution with pandas:

```
import pandas as pd
df = pd.read_csv(csvfile,names=['ID','Year','Value'])
df['Year'] = df['Year'].astype(int)
df.groupby(['Year']).mean()
```

Comment: thanks for the solution. is there a more sophisticated way of doing this? maybe with pandas or something?

Comment: i ran that code, but i get this error message: invalid literal for int() with base 10: 'year'

Comment: i think for some reason pandas is trying to convert the header to and integer

Comment: The code assumes that your file does NOT have a header already. I tried on the snippet you provided, and it works perfectly.